# Problems with saving changes in layerproperties (Qgis)

Tags: qgis

I have problems with layerproperties in Qgis. I load a shapefile, edit textsize and color and do labeling some points with text. After i saved the layer as shapefile again and open it......all changes as edited color and textlabeling are gone. Do someone know what exactly the problem could be?

Regards Prospekteur

Answer (score 2):

The Shapefile format is not capable of saving the styles you have set in QGIS.
To work around this issue QGIS can create a default style file (.qml) that it will read when he load the .shp.

To save a default style in QGIS, in the property panel click on the style button (at the bottom left of the panel) and press the Save as default option. this will a .qml file with the same name as the .shp.

Comment: Thank you so much! Heres the only place in the web, where you really get help;-)